# Only horizontal Lines are Drawn with Debug.DrawLine in GameView

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to create a Grid with Unity. For Debugging Purpose, I want to Draw the Boxes with Debug.DrawLine.

```
//Drawe Grid Box Lines
//Horizontal Lines
Debug.DrawLine(GetWorldPosition(x, y), GetWorldPosition(x + 1, y), Color.white, 100f);
Debug.Log("Line Drawn: " + GetWorldPosition(x, y) + ", " + GetWorldPosition(x + 1, y));
//Vertical Lines
Debug.DrawLine(GetWorldPosition(x, y), GetWorldPosition(x, y + 1), Color.white, 100f);
Debug.Log("Line Drawn: " + GetWorldPosition(x, y) + ", " + GetWorldPosition(x, y + 1));
```

In the SceneView, it's rendering fine:

[image]

In the GameView instead, it only rendering the Vertical Lines:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why only the Vertical lines are printed?

The Debug.Log shows me one correct Line for all Lines, Vertical and Horizontal.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried zooming in & out the game view? Also maybe try disabling depthTest. (Add another parameter at the end of the function call, that's value should be false)

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer, if it helped please accept it as the answer to this question.

Comment: Just in general: you know this is only for debugging and afaik not going to be displayed in the final app, only within the Editor itself?

Comment: Exactly, there is the "line renderer" component for actual game pruposes. There you can also set a line width which ensures that the visual result is not that pixel critical.

Comment: You can not use debug.drawline in the final game, use

Comment: You see those line bcs you are selecting object that refer to those lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a rendering anomaly. If you zoom in in the game view, the lines will show up.